# Is it possible in Spark to run concurrent jobs on the same SparkSession?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am an amateur Spark user and Scala. Although I did numerous searches, I could not find my answer.
Is it possible to assign different tasks to different executors at the same time on a single driver program?
for example, Suppose we have 10 nodes. I want to write a code to classify a dataset using Naive Bayes algorithm with five workers and at the same time, I want to assign the other five workers a task to classify the dataset with the decision tree algorithm. Afterward, I will combine the the answers.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Spark's execution model defines tasks based on data partitions. If you have already tried running a spark job with both the classifications in the same driver, please share code insights and also the real issue which is causing you to ask the above question. It would help us to help you better

Answer (score 2):

HamidReza,

What you want to achieve is running two actions in parallel from your driver. It's definately possible but it only makes sense if your actions are not using the whole cluster (for a better resource management in fact).

You can use concurrency for this. There are many ways of implementing a concurrent program, starting with `Futures` (I can't really recommend this approach, but seems to be the most popular choice in Scala), to more advanced types like Tasks (you can take a look to popular functional libraries like `Monix`, `Cats` or `Zio`).